# Symfony - No route found when token in url

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on adding a reset password feature on an existing Symfony app and so fare I managed to get half the job done lol I am stuck on making the URL with the token work.

I receive by email the following link:
[...]/intranet/forgot-password/1066dc12cb38651660756e6f7b9e936a8a128371bd7d8de304

When I click that i get:
No route found for "GET /forgot-password/1066dc12cb38651660756e6f7b9e936a8a128371bd7d8de304"

My routing file looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_GOD: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MANAGE_USER, ROLE_MANAGE_CATEGORY, ROLE_MANAGE_TITLE, ROLE_MANAGE_DOCUMENT, ROLE_MANAGE_ARTICLE, ROLE_MANAGE_COURSE, ROLE_MANAGE_SAE]

    providers:
        our_users:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: email }

    firewalls:           
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.security.login_form_authenticator

            logout:
                path: /logout
            switch_user: ~
        forgot_password:
             pattern:  ^/api/forgot-password
             anonymous: true
        reset_password:
             pattern:  ^/api/reset-password
             anonymous: true
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/share, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/forgot-password,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/reset-password/,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,                   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

And my routing file looks like this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.reset:
    path:   '/api/forgot-password'
    defaults:  { _controller:  coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.forgot_password:resetPasswordAction}
    methods:  [POST]

coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update:
    path:   '/reset-password/{tokenValue}'
    defaults:  { _controller: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.forgot_password:updatePasswordAction}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's that `intranet` prefix?

Comment: In your routing you have `/reset-password` instead of `/forgot-password`. Is that it? Anyway there is no `forgot-password` route in your code.

Comment: @Federkun it looks like part of app base url, because the error says that symfony is looking for url starting with `/forgot-password`.

Comment: Thanks guys it was indeed reset that needs to receive the token!

Answer (score 1):

```
coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.reset:
    path:   '/api/forgot-password'
    defaults:  { _controller:  coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.forgot_password:resetPasswordAction}
    methods:  [POST]
```

Are you trying to reach `/api/forgot-password` using a POST request? Probably not, change that to allow `GET`. Also, the path should include the `{token}` as well.

Also, there's a a typo. Replace

```
- { path: ^/api/forgot-password,   role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

to

```
- { path: ^/api/forgot-password,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: He's not trying to reach `/api/*` at all. And there's no token parameter in this route.

Comment: Actualy forgot-password generates the token and sends the email. reset-password gets the token and shows the view to change the password. I got both mixed up. Thx for the typo thought. It worked with or with out an S at roles ... But might as well get it right lol thx!